# Xcode-9 Bot email notification not working

Tags: ios, swift, continuous-integration, xcode9, xcode-bots

I have successfully implement Continues Integration with Xcode 9 bot using [this blog](https://medium.com/xcblog/xcode9-xcode-server-comprehensive-ios-continuous-integration-3613a7973b48).

It is working fine.
But issue is I am not getting any mail after successfully integration done.

Please find attached screenshots:

[image]
[image]

I have not done any extra setting.
Let me know If i miss any done anything wrong.

Comment: Don't down vote without explaining problem.

Comment: [I didn't down-vote] The close vote probably explains the down-vote.

Comment: @LinusGeffarth; Can you help me what i am missing here?

Comment: I have never used Xcode's *Server & Bots* tool, so I have no idea how it works, sorry.